# Can we create iframe apps via the api?

Tags: facebook

I am adding app to fan page as a tab.I wanted to create many tab to my facebook page.Does I need to create diffrent app for that.Can we create app through code or any api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An app can only be added one time to any given page as a tab.  So you'll need to create an app for each tab you'd like to display.

At this time there is no current method of creating an app via code.  There was previously a method with the old connect product but it seems to have become obsolete.

Comment: Hi Dustin Nielson,thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi, I have created a facebook app but can I can get the app_id on the iframe page  ???